# Facebook Pixel: mismatched content_id values - how to fix?

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I would greatly appreciate some help with my current Facebook catalog ad predicament.

- For a product with stock number **12345**, our data feed brings it into the Facebook catalog as **616_12345** (the 616_ is consistent). This is the content_id.
- To match the FB pixel content_id and track events, the stock number in the catalog needs to match the stock number on the site. So no events are being recorded.
- I am managing the pixel and events through Google Tag Manager. I have set up a CSS selector that points to the stock number in an unordered list, but of course it just returns **12345**.

Is there a way to create a variable in GTM that assumes a "**616_**" will be added before the stock number?

I've been told there is no way to remove that 616_ from the data feed - so this is the only option I can think of.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way to create a variable in GTM - simple create "Constant" variable and set its' value to "616_". You can then reference this variable in your events and tags by simply using double curly brackets like so: `{{VariableName}}` . You can find detailed information [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/).

Comment: Thanks for the help!